# How powerful of an electric current would I need to fully ionize plasma under the specific circumstances below?

Tags: electricity, electrons, voltage, plasma-physics, ions

in a cylinder shaped vacuum chamber 4 inches in height and 5 in diameter at 1/100th atmosphere, with 3 cathodes at the face arranged in a equilateral triangle in exactly between the center and and the edge of the container and three anodes at the same location at the opposite face how much power for each anode cathode pair would it take to fully ionize the remaining air inside, into plasma  in volts and amps, if there are multiple combinations of volts and amps please feel free state any combination of volts and amps that works.

I am building plasma chamber to experiment with plasma

If you have any questions feel free to ask,

also if it's not possible to fully ionize the plasma I would Like to know how close I could get, and how much power that would require.

Comment: Look at the following answer [https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/233126/59023](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/233126/59023), specifically the ionization part, and instead of using the volume of all of Earth's atmosphere, use your cylindrical chamber.  That will give you an estimate for the total amount of energy needed.  The time scales would need to be short, thus the power required would likely be rather high.

Comment: But wouldn't it require different amounts of energy depending on the voltage and amperage?

Comment: Also that's only to ionize it in a instant, I need to know how to MAINTAIN that ionization for a prolonged period of time.

Comment: Also I'm in high school, and I do not believe I know the formulas necessary for those calculations…

Comment: If you managed to fully ionize the particles, it would not be so much of an issue to maintain.  Plasmas tend to go to a quasi-neutral state where they do not recombine quickly (actually, they can remain in a state of ions and electrons for very very long times... most of space is filled with plasmas).