# How close would a supernova be to endanger the astronauts on the ISS?

Tags: estimation, satellites, gamma-rays, space-travel, supernova

How close would a supernova be to endanger the astronauts on the ISS?
Would Betelgeuse be close enough?

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/232199/59023

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon type, a supernova could affect the Earth biosphere from a distance of 3 000 light years. A type II supernova nearer than about 25 light years could destroy half the ozone layer. Betelgeuse is estimated at about 700 light years. If it were to go supernova now, it would certainly have an impact, but it is predicted to move much further away before that will actually happen.